# Fixed size (not scrollable) ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I know this issue has been discussed before, but I haven't found a suitable answer.
I'd like to have a table with 3 rows and 2 columns. The left column would be a title, and the right column would be a list of items.

Hence I have 3 lists, one below the other, and I would like to make the whole screen scrollable (not each list scrollable separately).

The solution would be to use a `ScrollView` as the main component, then a `TableView`, then a `ListView` in the right columns of the table. The problem is that `ListView` is a scrollable component and won't work inside a `ScrollView`.

My question - is there any component, be it part of Android API or third party, that has the `ListView` functionality but is fixed size? I would like to enjoy the adapter functionality and the `onItemClick()` functionality (that gives me the clicked item's position).

Thanks

Edit: I tried the suggestion to set the height of the `ListView` manually, the result was that the area where the `ListView` was supposed to be indeed expanded as necessary, but the list elements were not displayed.

I used the following code:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lv.getLayoutParams());
lParams.height = calculateHeight(lv);
lv.setLayoutParams(lParams);
```

Without the last 3 lines it works just fine, but then the size is fixed, which brings me back to my original problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what your asking but if the problem lies in the fact that a listview is a scrollable item could you not just use the `setScrollContainer(boolean isScrollContainer)` to basically disable scrolling on the listview?   ... link to android docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollContainer(boolean)

Comment: *and I would like to make the whole screen scrollable (not each list scrollable separately).* and *I would like to enjoy the adapter functionality and the onItemClick() functionality* this two sentences contradict themselves. If you're going to show the `ListView` without being scrollable(show all of it?), then the adapter is useless and you are better off building the list manually. If you want something else please explain.

Comment: @Luksprog, Ok, say that I manually populate the list, although the adapter is a nice way to do it, how can I set the `onClick()` of each element to send the position of the element in the list? Do I have to set dynamic IDs with number and then parse them into int or is there a more built-in way? Also the `ListView` has animation effect when clicking elements, I would have to implement that myself too? I understand it's possible to implement something similar to ListView myself, I just hoped there is something out there to save me the work.

Comment: You'll need to use ids to reference the "rows" but this is dead easy to do. In the for loop for the creation of the rows, set an id(incrementing value)so you can retrieve it in the `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 2):

What i assume from your expectation is you are looking for

( Title, (ListView) )

( Title, (ListView) )

( Title, (ListView) )

If this is the what you are looking for, then you can use tableView as main layout, and you can make the listView not scrollable by giving its fixed height.

How to do it is, you need to measure the height of each child view's height and its divider height and set the listview's layout params to its exact height, then listview wont be scrollable, but the whole tableview is scrollable.

I would like you to take a look at this link.
http://iserveandroid.blogspot.sg/2011/06/how-to-calculate-lsitviews-total.html

Once you set the layout as content view, you need to set the adapters to the listviews, and immediately you need to set the (calculated height)layoutparams to the listviews.

Comment: I'll try that, although I was hoping for something that is less of a 'hack'. Does the code in your link take into account padding, margin, etc?

Comment: Yes it would be taken into account.